# Scrollbar on fixed div being cut off at bottom. Have fiddle for you to see

Tags: html, css

I have a left side div that is fixed in place. Inside I have another div that has overflow-y: auto. When this div has a scrollbar, it get cut off at the bottom. I'm not sure how to fix this. Please help. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8zz1hLc/

Some code:

```
<div class="left-panel">
<div class="logo-box">Logo</div>
<div class="orange-button">Main Menu</div>
<div class="left-control-box">
<div class="left-control-scroll">
abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg<br />abcdefg
<br /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="top-panel">
```

```
.left-panel {
width: 240px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
.logo-box {
width: 239px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #286ab4;
}
.orange-button {
height: 75px;
width: 239px;
background-color: #ff7a18;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.left-control-box {
width:239px;
background-color: #cfcfcf;
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
}
.top-panel {
min-height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 240px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #286ab4;
color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `vh` unit is equal to 1/100 viewport height. `100vh` is equal to the entire viewport height. Since your div starts below the top of the viewport, you can't see the bottom of it. You can solve this using css3 `calc()`.

`height: calc(100vh - 75px - 50px);`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8zz1hLc/1/)